# VBA getting top 2 integer values in a list of 5 integers

Tags: excel, vba, office365

My code has five integers values that are being fetched from some textboxes.

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e As Integer
a=CInt(frmform.textbox1.text)
b=CInt(frmform.textbox2.text)
c=CInt(frmform.textbox3.text)
d=CInt(frmform.textbox4.text)
e=CInt(frmform.textbox5.text)
```

I want to compare these five values and get the top two values so that I can print the original description of the variables to my 2 output textboxes like shown below:

Let's assume that a and b are the top two integers and their descriptions are a = High Growth Leader and b = Niche Business Leader. So I want to print their descriptions in my output textboxes like shown below.

```
frmform.TextBox1.Text="The first role is High Growth Leader"
frmform.TextBox2.Text="The second top role is Niche Business Leader"
```

How to achieve this in the simplest way possible.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: As of now what I have done is, I have created an array, added these five integers to it and sorted it so that I have the top 2 values on the first two index of the array. Then I am writing some if else statements to compare the sorted value with the original variables and if they are matching then I am printing their descriptions. But not sure if this is the right way to do, I am very new to vba so lagging a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by the following ways,

1. I created a new sheet and added the variable description in column 1
2. In the code I assigned the respective variables values to their description in column 2
3. Recorded marco to sort the column 2 from highest to lowest values by extending it for column 1 as well. Here is the code

```
Sub Score_sort()
'
' Score_sort Macro
    Range("C100:C104").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Competency Scoring").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Competency Scoring").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("C100"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Competency Scoring").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B100:C104")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

4. Now I have description value pair sorted in descending order and in the code I wrote the below to pick up the top two descriptions from the sheet and put it in the textboxes.

```
frmform.TextBox31.Text = Sheet2.Cells(100, 2).Value
frmform.TextBox32.Text = Sheet2.Cells(101, 2).Value
```